# Validation doesn't work for image upload in laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have problem when validating inputs. All input fields pass the validation process except image fields.

This is my file upload code in html:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="fileInput"> Cover picture: </label>
    <div class="controls">
      {!! Form::file('cover') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

And how I get data from view in controller:

```
$datas = array(
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'color' => Input::get('color'),
        'size' => Input::get('size'),
        'cover' => array('cover' => Input::file('cover'))
    );
```

And this is rules:

```
$rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'size' => 'required',
        'cover' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:10000'
    );
```

And Validation facades`s make method:

```
$validator = Validator::make($datas, $rules);
```

As I mentioned earlier, all validation rules passed for input, but for image it gives me an error:

> The cover must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.

Now, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you uploading a JPEG, JPG, or PNG file?

Comment: Yes, I am uploading JPEG, JPG or PNG. But it still gives me an error.

Comment: Are you including `files => true` on your `Form::open` call?

Comment: Yes, ceejayoz. I have included 'files' => true in Form::open. But still get an error.

Comment: you're getting an "error" or you're getting the message and not expecting it?

Comment: `Input::file('cover')` should return an array of files without needing to make a secondary array under cover.. it is now multidimensional and not that expected.

Comment: Cayce, I am getting the message which is I specified above: 'The cover must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.' I am not expecting it because everything seems right.

Comment: remove |max:10000 and try ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should approach this a little differently...

If you instead just create your function like so..

```
// The Illumniate/Http/Request version of Request in laravel
public function yourFunction(Request $request){
    ....
    $rules = ...;
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
}
```

The expected format of the Validator is handled automatically because it returns it. And when it runs through you can handle everything the same you already have.

---

Since this is accepted. The way to actually fix it with the code above is to just remove the multi-dimensional array and just use `Input::file('cover')` as it returns an array on its own.

Comment: It is important to reiterate that the `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` is needed at the top of your controller file.

Comment: Thanks, Cayce K. As you said Input::file('cover') return array. And when I put it to another array it gives me two-dimensional array. When I remove array it worked. Thanks a lot.